# Cannot save scikit-learn model using joblib?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, lstm

I have the Ensemble model that combines both tensorflow and scikit-learn. And I would like to save this Ensemble model as a box to feed data in and generate the output. My code is as below

```
def model_base_LSTM(***):
   ***
model = model_base_LSTM(***)
ensem_model = BaggingRegressor(base_estimator=model, n_estimators=15)
ensem_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
bag_mod_pred = ensem_model.predict(x_test_bag)

from joblib import dump, load
dump(ensem_model, 'LSTM_Ensemble.joblib')
```

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects

So, how to solve this problem??

Comment: Is some sort of multithreading is happening in your logic?

Comment: Could you explain clearer?

Comment: While googling the error, I got https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/bl2vze/what_does_the_error_message_typeerror_cant_pickle/ which says your are trying to store a `threading.lock` object which belongs to OS.

Answer (score 0):

## You can save your TensorFlow (and even PyTorch) models with Scikit-Learn, but only if you use [Neuraxle](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle) and its saving mechanics.

Neuraxle is an extension of Scikit-Learn to make it more compatible with all deep learning libraries.

> The trick is performed by using [Neuraxle-TensorFlow](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle-TensorFlow) or [Neuraxle-PyTorch](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle-PyTorch).

### Why so?

Using one of Neuraxle-TensorFlow or Neuraxle-PyTorch will provide you with a saver to allow your thing to be serialized correctly. You want it to be serialized correctly to be able to ensure compatibility between scikit-learn and your Deep Learning framework when it comes time to save or parallelize things and so forth. You can read how Neuraxle solves this with savers [here](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-you-can-t-parallelize-nor-save-pipelines-using-steps-that-can-t-be-serialized-as-is-by-joblib).

### Code Examples

Here is a full project example from A to Z where [TensorFlow is used with Neuraxle as if it was used with Scikit-Learn](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/seq2seq-signal-prediction).

Here is another practical example where [TensorFlow is used within a scikit-learn-like pipeline](https://github.com/Neuraxio/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition/blob/tmp-work/1_train_and_save_LSTM.ipynb)